# Getting error while fetching twitter api in react but work in postman

Tags: reactjs

It is regarding twitter api integration in react. I got the output in postman but getting in react code while fetching data.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get(
      'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1458693399138037761,1440916738858622978',
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization:
            'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMcSUQEAAAAAUrzNhYNWotZNhxTdNb1zm5yXrME%3DoDW9Ja6gRoDtORl8GDKtjfqrwJ4TDSb0Pa7Sg69cQOEieb69W', //the token is a variable which holds the token'
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      // setPosts(res.data.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow,  please do update the question with the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: please put your error stack trace, what exact issue, man, is it CORS pre flight, whats it